# do.call error, more elements supplied than there are to replace (fixed with rlang::invoke) [R]

Tags: r, debugging, rlang, do.call

I getting a strange error when passing a list of arguments (only one for making simpler) to `do.call`... it would be fixed by using `rlang::invoke` instead but I'd like to understand what's happening here. Thanks.

```
> mydata <- source("https://pastebin.com/raw/bL8ZHvbt")$value
f <- as.formula(paste0("Surv(OS, Death) ~ ", paste(colnames(mydata)[-c(7:8)], collapse = " + ")))

> SurvBoost::boosting_core(formula = f, data = mydata, rate = 0.1)
$call
SurvBoost::boosting_core(formula = f, data = mydata, rate = 0.1)

$coefficients
Double_positive_CD4p_CD8dim      TCD4p_CM_CD127low_PD1n      TCD4p_CM_CD127low_PD1p  TCD4p_CM_CD127p_CD25p_PD1n        TCD4p_CM_CD127p_PD1n 
                 0.15576408                 -0.03984465                 -0.22904226                 -0.03556506                 -0.15901050 
     TCD4p_EM_CD127low_PD1n 
                 0.04126120 

> do.call(SurvBoost::boosting_core, c(list(formula = f, data = as.data.frame(mydata)), list(rate = 0.1)))
Error in names(output)[[1]] <- data_name : 
  more elements supplied than there are to replace

> rlang::invoke(SurvBoost::boosting_core, c(list(formula = f, data = as.data.frame(mydata)), list(rate = 0.1)))
$call
.fn(formula = `1`, data = `2`, rate = `3`)

$coefficients
Double_positive_CD4p_CD8dim      TCD4p_CM_CD127low_PD1n      TCD4p_CM_CD127low_PD1p  TCD4p_CM_CD127p_CD25p_PD1n        TCD4p_CM_CD127p_PD1n 
                 0.15576408                 -0.03984465                 -0.22904226                 -0.03556506                 -0.15901050 
     TCD4p_EM_CD127low_PD1n 
                 0.04126120
```

Comment: `SurvBoost` was [removed from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=SurvBoost) so it makes it difficult to run and test what's going on.

Comment: You can try `do.call(SurvBoost::boosting_core, c(list(formula = quote(f), data = quote(as.data.frame(mydata))), list(rate = 0.1)))` for something that will be more like the original.

Comment: It works nicely, thanks. What's doing `quote` exactly??